# How to remove all files having 10 characters in name with bat?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have thousands of generated php files in a folder that are not necessary. They all having the same naming structure of 10 characters each example "rk9qiaLOaf.php".

But I don't want to delete all because the folder contains index.php,main.php such important files and I don't want them to be deleted.

Please, how can it be done to delete the files within a folder they all are having name count of 10 by a batch script. Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use this from the Command prompt:

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Where/F "C:\Users\Aung\Documents:??????????.php"') Do @Del %A
```

Just change the folder path as appropriate.

**Edit**

A recursive version, *(could take a while)*.

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Where/F /R "C:\Users\Aung" "??????????.php"') Do @Del %A
```

Once again just change the root folder, *(use **.** for the current directory)* as necessary.

Comment: +1, Very cool. I had no idea you could use WHERE in this way. There are multiple key points with this command. **1)** It is ***critical*** that the path be specified, else WHERE will include files that are within your PATH folders. **2)** WHERE uses different wildcard rules then most other commands - WHERE treats `?` as any 1 character, whereas most other commands treat `?` as any 0 or 1 character. **3)** WHERE ignores short file names (which is great), whereas most other commands also match short names (causing problems). Points 2 & 3 make this command really useful :-) Thanks for posting.

Comment: What a great cmd master . thousands of junk files had gone within a second after treated with this code. But with path, it showing pattern not match, may be spaces between it. 
I go to root dir and tried it 

--->For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Where/F "??????????.php"') Do @Del %A<---

Perfect ! Thank you so much .

Comment: The 'no matching' message would only occur if there were no file names with 10 characters. The message isn't sent to stderr and is harmless, _(I find it more useful than not)_. I have included as an edit an additional option for a recursive search.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) together with [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter for the correct files:

```cmd
dir /B /A:-D "*.php" | findstr /I "^..........\.php$"
```

Every dot `.` matches a single character. `^` and `$` ensure to match the whole file name.

To delete the returned files, use this in command prompt `cmd`:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*.php" ^| findstr /I "^..........\.php$"') do @del "%F"
```

Or this in a batch file:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*.php" ^| findstr /I "^..........\.php$"') do del "%%F"
```

---

And here is an alternative batch file approach relying on [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*.php"') do (
    set "NAME=%%~nF" & set "EXT=%%~xF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check whether file name is not longer than 10 characters:
    if "!NAME!"=="!NAME:~,10!" (
        rem // Check whether file name is longer than 9 characters:
        if not "!NAME:~9!"=="" (
            del "!NAME!!EXT!"
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```